# Manipulating matrix demension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am trying to put values from one array to another in a certain order. However they are placed in the array in the same dimension as the original.

```
nodeState = [2 8 5; 1 6 4; 9 0 5];

cState = [];

cState = [nodeState(1,1) nodeState(1,2) nodeState(1,3)
                    nodeState(2,3) nodeState(3,3) nodeState(3,2)
                    nodeState(3,1) nodeState(2,1) nodeState(2,2)];
```

What I am expecting is for my `cState` to be of this demension

`2 8 5 4 5 0 9 1 6`

instead of this demension

```
2     8     5

4     5     0

9     1     6
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split a declaration into multiple lines you must use `...` otherwise Matlab interprets the Carriage returns as a new row, so it will create a matrix instead of a vector.

Just do:

```
cState = [nodeState(1,1) nodeState(1,2) nodeState(1,3) ...
          nodeState(2,3) nodeState(3,3) nodeState(3,2) ...
          nodeState(3,1) nodeState(2,1) nodeState(2,2)];
```

Comment: Wow this is it! they need to put this in beginners documentation.

Comment: @Jam1 It actually is, though it's a bit hard to find: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-29 - See *Defining Arrays*.

Comment: I really think Matlab should force users to use a semicolon `;` to start a new row to avoid confusions like this one. Also in my opinion allowing the use of space to separate columns is a bad idea. Users should be forced to use comma `,` and semicolon `;` when filling matrix values. I think they don't do it for compatibility reasons, since that would break tons of existing programs.